# Why Al-Maidah verse 5:90 described Satan like a real person?

Tags: quran, shaitan, surat-al-maidah

Since childhood, I have been taught about the Satan. Satan is a creature of the unseen and its task is to tempt humans to deny Allah. They're the real enemy to all humans.

But when I read Surah Al-Maidah verse 5:90, it mentions among the deeds of Satan, drinking alcohol, gambling, idol worship, and seeking omens. These are all actions performed by humans, not by unseen beings, let alone those whose specific task is to tempt the mankind.

So is that mean the Satan is actually referred to real humans physically, and the actual meaning of the clear enemy (mubeen) is the visible enemy in front of our eyes, which humans can clearly and distinctly recognize?

Comment: How do you know what are actions of unseen beings? They're unseen. You can't see them.

Comment: @goldPseudo are you saying that there are invisible beers? or invisible stones? :D

Comment: Why not? Why are those any less believable than invisible beings made of smokeless fire who whisper evil desires into the hearts of mankind?

Comment: @goldPseudo because beers and idols are totally human made. i'm convinced that there's no such thing as invisible wines, invisible stones, invisible clothes, invisible cars, invisible apartments, let alone they're belong to the satan to use them against us

Answer (score 1):

Shaytan (Satan) is an unseen being. When Allah ta'ala says that drinking, gambling, sacrificing to other than Allah, etc. are "defilement from the work of Satan", what that means is that these actions are Satanic and inspired by Shaytan, who is the "whisperer" that suggests these evil thoughts and actions to humans who do these things.

However, the Quran also mentions that there are both human and jinn Satans; indicating that anyone who tempts others to do evil or turn away from Allah is a satan. For example, in Surah Al-An'am (6:112), Allah says:

> "And thus We have made for every prophet an enemy - devils from
> mankind and jinn, inspiring to one another decorative speech in
> delusion...

This verse clearly states that there are devils (or Satans) among both humans and jinn.

Both human and jinn satans encourage evil actions, disobey Allah, and lead others away from the path of truth. Human satans do this through their words, actions and influence. Therefore, having good company (and avoiding bad company) is extremely important.